# Kotlin - How do I concatenate a String to an Int value?

Tags: kotlin

A very basic question, What is the right approach to concatenate String to an Int? 
I'm new in Kotlin and want to print an `Integer` value preceding with String and getting the following error message.

```
for (i in 15 downTo 10){
  print(i + " "); //error: None of the following function can be called with the argument supplied:
  print(i); //It's Working but I need some space after the integer value.
}
```

*Expected Outcome*
15 14 13 12 11 10

Comment: Use this syntax `print("$i ")` when using Kotlin.

Comment: Thank you @JeelVankhede, it's working for me ;)

Answer (score 8):

You've got several options:

**1. String templates**. I think it is the best one. It works absolutely like 2-st solution, but looks better and allow to add some needed characters.

```
print("$i")
```

and if you want to add something

```
print("$i ")
print("$i - is good")
```

to add some expression place it in brackets

```
print("${i + 1} - is better")
```

**2. `toString` method** which can be used for any object in kotlin.

```
print(i.toString())
```

**3. Java-like solution** with concatenating

```
print("" + i)
```

Comment: In Java print( "" + i) and print( i + "") both work but in Kotlin only print( "" + i ) works. Why print( i + "") does not work in Kotlin?

Comment: In kotlin concatenation operation isn't defined in this way. From some point of view it even seems logical - you can add any number to string, but what you should expect from adding string to number? Anyway, kotlin haven't such option)

Answer (score 3):

`$` dollar – Dollar symbol is used in String templates that we’ll be seeing next

```
for (i in 15 downTo 10){   
  print("$i ")
}
```

Output : 15  14  13  12  11  10

Comment: What the point of `str` val? You are also inconsistent about using semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

You can use kotlin string template for that:

```
for (i in 15 downTo 10){
  print("$i ");
}
```

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#string-templates

Answer (score 1):

The `Int::toString` method does what you're looking for. Instead of explicit loops, consider functional approaches like `map`:

```
(15 downTo 10).map(Int::toString).joinToString { " " }
```

Note that the `map` part is even redundant since `joinToString` can handle the conversion internally.

Answer (score 1):

The error you get is because the `+` you're using is the integer one (it is decided by the left operand). The integer `+` expects 2 integers. In order to actually use the `+` of String for concatenation, you would need the string on the left, like `"" + i + " "`.

That being said, it is more idiomatic in Kotlin to print formatted strings using **string templates**: `"$i "`

However, if all you want is to print integers with spaces in between, you can use the stdlib function `joinToString()`:

```
val output = (15 downTo 10).joinToString(" ")
print(output) // or println() if you want to start a new line after your integers
```

Answer (score 0):

Just cast to String:

```
for (i in 15 downTo 10){
  print(i.toString() + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `$` . You can also use the + but it could get confusing in your case because the + has is also an operator which invokes the `plus()` method which is used to sum Integers.

```
for (i in 15 downTo 10){
  print("$i ");
}
```